# Exception handling and `Getopt::Long`

Tags: perl, exception

Why does this script continue to run and not die, when I pass an invalid file-name?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions :config bundling);

sub help {
    say "no help text";
}

sub read_config {
    my $file = shift;
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
    say <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}

sub helpers_dispatch_table {
    return {
        'h_help'                => \&help,
        'r_read'                => \&read_config,
    };
}

my $file_conf = 'does_not_exist.txt';
my $helpers = helpers_dispatch_table();

GetOptions (
    'h|help'            => sub { $helpers->{h_help}(); exit; },
    'r|read'            => sub { $helpers->{r_read}( $file_conf ); exit },
);

say "Hello, World!\n" x 5;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From **perldoc Getopt::Long**

```
   A trivial application of this mechanism is to implement options that are related to each other. For example:

       my $verbose = '';   # option variable with default value (false)
       GetOptions ('verbose' => \$verbose,
                   'quiet'   => sub { $verbose = 0 });

   Here "--verbose" and "--quiet" control the same variable $verbose, but with opposite values.

   If the subroutine needs to signal an error, it should call die() with the desired error message as its argument. GetOptions() will catch the die(),
   issue the error message, and record that an error result must be returned upon completion.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems your attempt to mixing two tasks, and from not checking if GetOptions found any errors.

Actually, fixing either bugs would have solved your problem, but here's how to fix both:

```
sub help {
   # Show usage
   exit(0);
}

sub usage {
   my $tool = basename($0);
   print(STDERR "$_[0]\n") if @_;
   print(STDERR "Usage: $tool [OPTIONS] FILE ...\n");
   print(STDERR "Try `$tool --help' for more information.\n");
   exit(1);
}

my $opt_read;
GetOptions (
    'h|help' => \&help,
    'r|read' => \$opt_read,
) or usage("Invalid arguments");

my $config = read_config($opt_read);
```

Comment: The name of the subroutine `read_config` is not a good one - it does not read in a config-file, it only prints the config-file to STDOUT for information. (the `helpers_dispatch_table` gets imported from a module).

Comment: @sid_com, All the more reason for it not to be done within `GetOptions`! Printing a file has nothing to do with getting args.

Comment: @sid_com, The only reason I call `help` in the middle of parsing args is that I don't want to parse any more args afterwards.